# Best way to identify different element states?

Tags: design-patterns, color-scheme

I maintain a reporting app and currently we're trying to come up with a new way to organize our settings page.

We display our settings in a table, this is used for displaying the setting/values only.

e.g.

```
Setting    Value
Name       Bob
Age        45
Pets       5
Fb Friends 80
Mood       Happy
Health     Fit
```

Behind the scenes, our Web App knows which settings are qualitative and which settings are quantitative, however, how do I convey that to the user? Grouping the qualitative/quantitative information together is not an option.

Comment: Can you customize the design or do you want to use only the text styles to highlight the different setting state?

Comment: I can customise the design.

Comment: A couple of clarifying questions: How many distinct qualitative "levels" need to be considered? (Basically, what are the levels/options for "health"?) Do you want the user to see the other levels, thereby encouraging them to "become more fit"? Or do you only want to display a single value/level at a time? Do you have upper limits on the quantitative values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to separate quantitative and qualitative information? Try two tabs, one for qualitative and one for quantitative. Or you could separate the information into regions using alignment grids, borders and frames, area fills, white space, and gestalt integration. Besides color which you mentioned earlier, your other options for marking something are texture and shape.

Maybe have one tab labeled 'Basic Info' and another labeled 'About Tyler.' Go ahead and use the person's name instead of Tyler.

Let me know if I'm understanding your question and the constraints.

Comment: I updated the question to explain my problem better, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks, Tyler, I think this is perhaps the simplest solution.

Comment: Booya! (I need more words to post this. If you want to brainstorm more ideas, we can always play "Yes, and." Here's how you play: I give an idea. You say, "Yes! And..." with some more ideas after and. Then I say, "Yes, and we could" and so on. Give it a try. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the reasoning is behind the requirement of visually identifying the quantitative entries against the qualitative entries. But here's 3 different ways to do it.

You can highlight the rows that are quantitative (with gentle colors just enough to stand out but not off-putting)

[image]

Or you can display an icon (what icon you pick depends on why you want the quantitative ones to be called out from the rest. In this example below, I just used a hash sign).

[image]

Or you can use a combination of both the ideas above as shown below.

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Girish, I really like this answer but to keep things simple I might have to go with Tyler's answer.